# How to selectively import module in python?

Tags: python, coding-style

I have several different modules, and I need to import one of them depending on different situations, for example:

```
if check_situation() == 1:
    import helper_1 as helper
elif check_situation() == 2:
    import helper_2 as helper
elif ...
    ...
else:
    import helper_0 as helper
```

these helpers contain same dictionaries `dict01`, `dict02`, `dict03`...but have different values to be called in different situations.

But this has some problems:

1. import sentences are all written in the top of a file, but `check_situation()` function here needs prerequisites so that it's now far from top.
2. more than 1 file needs this helper module, so it's hard and ugly to use this kind of import.

So, how to re-arrange these helpers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solve it myself, refered to @Michael Scott Cuthbert

```
# re_direct.py

import this_module
import that_module

wanted = None


# caller.py
import re-direct

'''
many prerequisites
'''
def imp_now(case):
    import re_direct
    if case1:
        re_direct.wanted = re_direct.this_module
    elif case2:
        re_direct.wanted = re_direct.that_module
```

then, if in caller, I call that imp_now, then wanted, no matter called in caller file or other file calling this wanted, will all be re-directed to this_or_that_module.

also, for I import re_direct only in a function, so you will not see this module anywhere else, but only see wanted.

Comment: Also note that once you import `wanted` you can't change it by assigning to it from `re_direct.wanted`. The import redirection is totally unnecessary here.

Comment: @DavideR. yes i find it still don't work well. I don't care about load all modules or it can't change any more. Then how can I do to make all callers import this_module or that_module?

Answer (score 5):

You can use `__import__()`, it accepts a string and returns that module:

```
helper=__import__("helper_{0}".format(check_situation()))
```

example :

```
In [10]: mod=__import__("{0}math".format(raw_input("enter 'c' or '': ")))
enter 'c' or '': c             #imports cmath

In [11]: mod.__file__
Out[11]: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/cmath.so'

In [12]: mod=__import__("{0}math".format(raw_input("enter 'c' or '': ")))
enter 'c' or '': 

In [13]: mod.__file__
Out[13]: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/math.so'
```

As pointed out by @wim and from python3.x docs on `__import__()`:

> Import a module. Because this function is meant for use by the Python
>   interpreter and not for general use it is better to use
>   `importlib.import_module()` to programmatically import a module.

Comment: -1 because read the docstring of `__import__` - _"this function is meant for use by the Python
interpreter and not for general use it is better to use
importlib.import_module() to programmatically import a module"_

Comment: also, you've kind of ignored the "problem behind the problem", i.e. that the OP is using data in their variable names

Comment: @wim I can't seem to find the same thing in the docstring or the docs, from the docs: *This function is invoked by the import statement. Direct use of __import__() is rare, except in cases where you want to import a module whose name is only known at runtime.*

Comment: You are probably using an older version of python.  Check in `__import__.__doc__` on v3.2.3 (it seems this snippet of information is not there in 2.7.3)

Comment: @wim I've added a note about that, but my above example works fine in py3.x

Answer (score 5):

Firstly, there is no strict requirement that import statements need to be at the top of a file, it is more a style guide thing.

Now, `importlib` and a `dict` can be used to replace your `if`/`elif` chain:

```
import importlib

d = {1: 'helper_1', 2: 'helper_2'}
helper = importlib.import_module(d.get(check_situation(), 'helper_0'))
```

But it's just syntactic sugar really, I suspect you have bigger fish to fry.  It sounds like you need to reconsider your data structures, and redesign code.

Anytime you have variables named like `dict01`, `dict02`, `dict03` it is a sure sign that you need to gear up a level, and have some container of `dicts` e.g. a list of them.  Same goes for your 'helper' module names ending with digits.

Comment: yes I think it really need redesign. as original script, if import i can just use helper.dictA, helper.dictB without aware of which helper used. How to achieve this effect?

Comment: You could alias them in the modules, i.e. `my_dict = dictA` in one helper module and `my_dict = dictB` in the other.  Then access with `helper.my_dict`.  But I've got to stress that this solves a technical problem, not a design problem.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that the approaches given in the other answers are closer to the main question posed in your title, but if the overhead on importing modules is low (as importing a couple of dictionaries likely is) and there are no side-effects to importing, in this case, you may be better off importing them all and selecting the proper dictionary later in the modules:

```
import helper_0
import helper_1
...
helperList = [helper_0, helper_1, helper_2...]
...
helper = helperList[check_situation()]
```